# C# Backgroundworker breaks loop for no obvious reason

Tags: c#, loops, backgroundworker, break

Before I get into the code let me explain what i'm trying to do. It's a simple checklist against an API, the api has a limit and I figured a way to break the limit with changing my ip easily from my router. It works great most of the time but at some point after re-connecting successfully the worker stops and I have to click the button again.

Here's the code, first the Form class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNameChecker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void chk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!checkNames.IsBusy)
            {
                checkNames.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        int last = 0;

        private void checkNames_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string namesList = "";

            string[] namesArray;

            if (names.InvokeRequired) names.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { namesList = names.Text; }));            
            else namesList = names.Text;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(namesList))
            {
                namesArray = namesList.Replace("\r","").Split('\n');
                while (last < namesArray.Length)
                {
                    string tempStr = NameChecker.check(namesArray[last].Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", ""));
                    if (tempStr == "available")
                    {
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Names\available.txt", true)) file.WriteLine(namesArray[last]);
                        last++;
                    }
                    else if (tempStr == "unavailable" || tempStr == "skep")
                    {
                        last++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while(!NameChecker.reconnect()); 
                    }
                }
                if (last >= namesArray.Length)  last = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second MyNameChecker class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNameChecker
{
    class NameChecker
    {
        public static string check(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) return "skep";
            string url = "https://example.com/api";
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string stringData = "{\"name\":\"" + name + "\"}";
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(stringData);
            webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            webRequest.Timeout = 60000;

            try
            {
                // Get the response ...
                using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(webResponse.Headers["RequestNum"])) return "retry";
                    else return status(webResponse);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                var res = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res.Headers["RequestNum"])) return "retry";
                else return status(res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Names\Exceptions.txt", true)) file.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return "retry";
            }
            return "retry";
        }

        private static string status(HttpWebResponse res)
        {
            switch((int)res.StatusCode)
            {
                case 201:
                    return "available";
                case 400:
                    return "unavailable";
                default:
                    return "retry";
            }
        }


        public static bool reconnect()
        {
            string url = "http://router.lan/cgi/b/is/_pppoe_/ov/?be=0&l0=1&l1=1&name=Internet";
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string stringData = "0=12&1=Internet&32=1";
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(stringData);
            webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            webRequest.Timeout = 25000;

            try
            {
                // Get the response ...
                using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    // Get the body stream
                    string body = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    if (body.Contains("Uptime:")) return true;

                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                var res = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                string body = new System.IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                if (body.Contains("Uptime:")) return true;

                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Names\Exceptions.txt", true)) file.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried everything I could from increasing the timeout to catch all exceptions but there's no exception recorded? I'm unable to figure this problem. Usually I go to sleep and let it do it's work but this is just not working as expected.

BTW I used fiddler to debug the requests and there was an odd header `Expect: 100-continue` i don't know if this has anything to do with the breaking but I thought it's better to mention it.

Comment: Extract the code into a console application and see if you can recreate the situation. If you can't that might show that the gui threading aspect is the culprit (maybe going cross thread?). Regardless the exercise might give you a hint to the issue which is tripping the code.

Comment: @OmegaMan I think I know why it's behaving like this but I don't know how to solve this. The problem arise when the re-connect takes longer than expected the process is terminated for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: Now I see the problem when a request take so long it breaks immediately. Anyone knows how to prevent this? I'm catching all exception and retrying but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.